# Changing the itemize label causes an error

Tags: errors, itemize

I need to change the itemize symbols. Firstly I tried this:

```
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\cdot}
```

which led to an error: "! Missing $ inserted". Then I tried this one:

```
 \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\cdot$}
```

and got: "! File ended while scanning use of \@argdef."
I can't figure out how what I am doing wrong.

Comment: oh, my bad, second piece of code should look this way: `\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\cdot$}`

Comment: You can edit your question, rather than adding corrections in comments. Since there's nothing wrong in the second piece of code (with `$` signs), the problem is somewhere else. Try  showing a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I'm curious to know what actually triggered the error. This `\renewcommand` works fine for me in a simple latex file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `\cdot` is a math symbol, you have to say

```
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\cdot$}
```

Or you can do

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

and then you can have

```
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\textperiodcentered}
```

Comment: Textcomp completely solves the problem, thank you!